# How do I configure two different triggers for a project in CruiseControl.Net?

Tags: cruisecontrol.net

I would like to know if its possible to create two triggers, one on a filesystem and another for an svn checkout in the same config file.
I have tried out the following:

a) have put both the triggers and their respective filesystem, svn definitions along with tasks in the same file, 
Results in error: It says unused node deteted
eg:

```
<trigggers>
<intervalTrigger seconds="100" buildCondition="ForceBuild"/> 
<intervalTrigger seconds="300" buildCondition="IfModificationExists"/> 
</triggers>

<sourcecontrol type="filesystem">
  <repositoryRoot>...</repositoryRoot>
</sourcecontrol>

<sourcecontrol type="svn">
 <trunkUrl>....</trunkUrl>
 <workingDirectory>...</workingDirectory>
 <executable>...\SVN.exe</executable>
 <username/>..<password/>
</sourcecontrol>

<tasks>
 <!-- To be carried out if either of the two triggers happen -->
</tasks>
```

b) have created different scopes for each of the trigger bound with respective filesystem/svn and tasks, also ends up with unused node detected error.

```
<cb:define first_trigger_and source _and_tasks>
 <triggers>
  <intervalTrigger seconds="300" buildCondition="ForceBuild"/> 
 </triggers>
 <sourcecontrol type="filesystem">
   <repositoryRoot>...</repositoryRoot>
 </sourcecontrol>
 <tasks>
  <!--To be carried out when first trigger happens -->
 </tasks>
</cb:define>

<!-- And then I call the trigger this way -->
<cb:first_trigger_and source _and_tasks>
```

Neither of those solution works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Multiple triggers can be specified inside the `<triggers>` block, but that is not why CruiseControl.Net is complaining when it's processing your configuration.

It seems to me that you want a *single* trigger, but *two* separate source control entries. The [`<triggers>`](http://confluence.public.thoughtworks.org/display/CCNET/Trigger+Blocks) entries specify when CruiseControl.Net should wake up and check the project state. You can't specify multiple `<sourcecontrol>` elements in a `<project>` block. To actually rebuild project on both (remote) svn changes and local filesystem changes, you should use [`<sourcecontrol type="multi">`](http://confluence.public.thoughtworks.org/display/CCNET/Multi+Source+Control+Block) with a standard trigger:

```
<triggers>
  <intervalTrigger seconds="30" />
</triggers>

<sourcecontrol type="multi">
  <sourceControls>
    <filesystem>
      <repositoryRoot>...</repositoryRoot>
    </filesystem>    
    <svn>
      <trunkUrl>....</trunkUrl>
      <workingDirectory>...</workingDirectory>
      <executable>...\SVN.exe</executable>
      <username/>..<password/>
    </svn>
  </sourceControls>
</sourcecontrol>

<tasks>
 <!-- To be executed if either of the two source control providers report changes -->
</tasks>
```

Comment: Thanks a ton, this worked. I had been trying to add two sources of triggers in one project file, and yes this code block accomplishes exactly that. :)